# Texture brush doesn't make clear or smooth geometry on sculpture

Tags: sculpting

I have a fairly dense sculpture over (1.5-2 million verts). I downloaded a texture! And assigned it to one of the brushes textures! When I tried sculpting over the sculpture,even with dyntopo and applying scale to the model, it kinda made a lowpoly stroke rather than a smooth stroke, what could be the problem?  Isn't it how you add details to your sculpts?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

These so-called Alpha brushes require a very high polycount to look good. I've done some tests with the [Lips Alpha brushes by Todor](https://cgdive.com/tutorial-skin-lips-blender-zbrush-free-alphas/). You can get the Light version here for free (https://gumroad.com/l/lipsfree) if you want to try it out yourself. It comes with a short manual for the brush settings.

The following images show the included example blend. The lips are low-poly with a Multires modifier, with 3, 4, and 5 subdivisions. 6 subdivisions (=2.4 million vertices) show no improvement in comparison to 5 subdivs.

If you have a fully sculpted character or creature you will end up easily with a few million verts like in this video: [Create High Resolution Sculptings in Blender](https://youtu.be/fw32i2dBfEo) (24 million verts)

If your PC can't handle such a high amount of verts you can use a Bump Map and paint the details on a texture as shown here: [Node Based Texture Painting in Blender 2 8](https://youtu.be/gUVEzwAgGzo)

Hope that helps :-)

[image: Lips with 37k vertices]
[image: Lips with 150k vertices]
[image: Lips with 600k vertices]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time and writing this to me!