# Why can't I get my alpha brush to paint textures using images?

Tags: texturing, sculpting, texture-painting, brushes, texture-paint-mode

Alpha brush not showing texture, tried with different files and images, all make the same unwanted effect.

The example below is what a simple click and drag does, this is with the strength at 1.0 but anything below does the same, just muffled distortions going in the same direction. All the tutorials gave clear instructions as this isn't a hard thing to do, but it just isn't working for me. I'm assuming it's some setting I overlooked/didn't know about.

I can't figure out how to add the image/video here so I'll link it to my reddit post about it. https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/q6ccbx/need_help_getting_alpha_brush_to_work/

Comment: How dense is the mesh? Alpha brushes require a lot of vertices, speaking of millions. For better performance, a MultiRes modifier on a low-poly retopo model is recommended.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much! Had some trouble not knowing that I had to apply mirror before I added the multiRes but that was a quick google away!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Texture brush doesn't make clear or smooth geometry on sculpture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/198573/texture-brush-doesnt-make-clear-or-smooth-geometry-on-sculpture)